# Pattern Matching fields but also have a variable that represents the entire datatype

Tags: haskell

I would like to pattern match on a function with the following sum type :

```
data CommandRequest  = CreateWorkspace {commandId :: UUID , workspaceId ::UUID }
                 | IntroduceIdea {commandId :: UUID , workspaceId ::UUID , ideaContent :: String}
```

So I know how to bind variables on the fields :

```
instance ToJSON CommandRequest where
   toJSON (CreateWorkspace commandId workspaceId) = object [
          "commandId" .= commandId,
          "workspaceId" .= workspaceId,
          "commandName" .= pack "createWorkspace"]
   toJSON (IntroduceIdea commandId workspaceId ideaContent) = object [
             "commandId" .= commandId,
             "workspaceId" .= workspaceId,
             "commandName" .= pack "introduceIdea",
             "ideaContent" .= ideaContent
             ]
```

I would like to bind the entire data type at the same time like we can do in scala :

```
toJSON ( myDataType  @ CreateWorkspace commandId workspaceId) = ...
```

Do you know how to do it in haskell ?

Answer (score 1):

It was an issue with parentheses !

```
instance ToJSON CommandRequest where
   toJSON (command @ (CreateWorkspace commandId workspaceId)) = object [
          "commandId" .= commandId,
          "workspaceId" .= workspaceId,
          "commandName" .= pack "createWorkspace"]
   toJSON (command @ (IntroduceIdea commandId workspaceId ideaContent)) = object [
             "commandId" .= commandId,
             "workspaceId" .= workspaceId,
             "commandName" .= getCommandName command,
             "ideaContent" .= ideaContent
             ]
```

Comment: You don't need the outer parens.